# How to update a component data from service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components

I have that component, and I need it to get current password strength updated real-time

```
import {Component, Input, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {CurrentPasswordStrengthService} from "../services/current-password-strength.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-indicator',
  templateUrl: './indicator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./indicator.component.scss']
})
export class IndicatorComponent {
  state = this.currentPasswordStrengthService.currentPasswordStrength();
  constructor(private currentPasswordStrengthService: CurrentPasswordStrengthService) {
  }


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```

that's the service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {PasswordStrength} from "../infrastructure/enums/password-strength.enum";
import {PasswordStrengthService} from "./password-strength.service";
import {CurrentPasswordService} from "./current-password.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurrentPasswordStrengthService {

  currentPasswordStrength() {
    return this.passwordStrengthService.passwordStrength(this.currentPasswordService.getPassword())
  }
  constructor(private passwordStrengthService: PasswordStrengthService, private currentPasswordService: CurrentPasswordService) { }
}
```

that's the password-form component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";

import {PasswordStrengthService} from "../services/password-strength.service";
import {CurrentPasswordService} from "../services/current-password.service";

//TODO: ad no-whitespace validator

@Component({
  selector: 'app-password-form',
  templateUrl: './password-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./password-form.component.scss'],
  providers: [PasswordStrengthService]
})
export class PasswordFormComponent implements OnInit{

  passwordControl = new FormControl();
  constructor(private currentPasswordService: CurrentPasswordService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.passwordControl.valueChanges.subscribe(change => {
      this.currentPasswordService.setPassword(this.passwordControl.value)
    });
  }

}
```

Is that approach optimal? If not what to do then? /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just made the `currentPasswordStrengthService` public:

```js
constructor(public currentPasswordStrengthService: CurrentPasswordStrengthService)
```

And as the main goal was to pass that `currentPasswordStrength` to the component's template, I passed it like this:

```
{{this.currentPasswordStrengthService.currentPasswordStrength()}}
```